# Best practice to process big plists?

Tags: ios, objective-c, plist

I'm using a plist file which contains all app my data. The file is quite big and currently I'm loading all the stuff into Arrays and Dictionaries at first launch and save them into UserDefaults so that I don't have to touch the plist again. As this takes about 10 secs (iP4) I wonder if there is an even faster (better) way to process the plist. I checked the whole startup with Instruments and going through the hundreds of entries is actually the fastest part. It takes very long to save these processed stuff into NSUserDefaults.

Comment: You know that you practically re-generate the plists without any advantage? `NSUserDefaults` stores info in plists as well.

Comment: You could do all the work in a GCD queue.  Right from the start create a normal background queue, give it a block that does your plist work. Like @H2CO3 suggested, put everything in NSUserDefault and create methods to get the data as needed. No need to put it in two places.

Comment: Is this because you have lots and lots of small data, or because you have some huge NSData objects? You should not be keeping those in plists (or NSUserDefaults, which is itself a plist).

Comment: Why not just copy the plist file to an application support directly and load it through `NSDictionary` instead of via `NSUserDefaults`?

Comment: *NSUserDefaults* isn't made for holding a big amount of data, for this purpose I suggest to use a sqlite3 database.

Answer (score 0):

You might benefit from saving the plist to your own file.  That way you control the reading/writing, don't have any overhead associated with NSUserDefaults, and, most importantly, can ensure the format.  That is, if reading/writing is producing the slow down, then you'll have to minimize the plist file size.  Likely using a plist format of `NSPropertyListBinaryFormat_v1_0` will do that:

See:

```
+ (NSInteger) writePropertyList: (id) plist 
                       toStream: (NSOutputStream *) stream 
                         format: (NSPropertyListFormat)format 
                        options: (NSPropertyListWriteOptions) opt 
                          error: (NSError **) error
```

From Apple's Property List Programming Guide:

> The first approach [using NSDictionary or NSArray writeToFile]  is
>   simpler—it  requires only one method invocation instead of two—but the
>   second approach [as above] has its advantages. It allows you to convert the
>   runtime property list to binary  format as well as an XML property
>   list. When you convert a static representation  of a property list
>   back into a graph of objects, it also lets you specify  with more
>   flexibility whether those objects are mutable or immutable.

Answer (score 0):

Several points.

1. NSUserDefaults is probably just a big plist, so why use it?  Stick your entries into a singleton that holds the in-memory structure.
2. If you're doing this on first load because you want it to be mutable, put the defaults into your resource folder.  When you want to load it, check if you have it in the documents folder, and if you don't ( first load), copy it from the resource bundle to the documents.
3. If you're using NSUserDefaults for persistence, just write out your data to your plist in applicationShouldResignActive, and at any other times where you make important changes.
4. Write it in a background thread, but you probably need to do some locking here.
5. Best practise when load and save times become to big is probably move to core data, but 1-4 should give you some more mileage before you need to do that.